# How to request JWindow temporary focus? (Java 1.7)

Tags: java, swing, focus, components, jwindow

Is it possible to request JWindow temporary focus? There is a method `protected boolean requestFocusInWindow(boolean temporary)`, but the method is protected.

Comment: could be possible for JComponents that are focusable (JTextComponents), but you probably play with top-level containers, search here for posts by @camickr about Dialog Focus/RequestFocusListener about AncestorListener, this could be way for you how to lock Focus ....

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, you are right. Look at my answer below - found new solution :) for custom caret, when JTextField lost it's focus and temporary focus is requested to parent JWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found the solution - in class which extends JWindow created this method:

```
@Override
public boolean requestFocusInWindow(boolean temporary) {
    return super.requestFocusInWindow(temporary);
}
```

Now I can request temporary focus for component which extends `JWindow`. I'm using it for my custom popup menu for `JTextField` where caret color is changed if selected when popup is visible (of course - `textField.setCaret(new HighlightCaret());` is necessary):

```
private class HighlightCaret extends DefaultCaret {

    private final Highlighter.HighlightPainter unfocusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
    private final Highlighter.HighlightPainter focusedPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(10, 36, 106));
    private boolean isTemporary;

    private HighlightCaret() {
        setBlinkRate(500);
    }

    @Override
    protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter() {
        return isTemporary ? unfocusedPainter : focusedPainter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectionVisible(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.setSelectionVisible(false);
        if (hasFocus) {
            super.setSelectionVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        isTemporary = false;
        super.focusGained(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        isTemporary = e.isTemporary();
        super.focusLost(e);
    }
}
```